# Livewire form is not sending data

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have this livewire component that works like the Facebook's timeline. It has a  where you can post your comments and it is working fine. But there is this button that shows form that I can send some data to the server, grab a response and print right above everything. This  send `cotacao` to the method `cotizar(Request $request)` but the `$request->cotacao` is always `null`.

Can't figure why. Let's see some code:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="cotizar">
            @csrf
            @method('POST')
            <input type="text" name="cotacao" class="form-control" wire:model.defer="cotacao" required>
            <span class="text-muted small">Digite as idades separadas por vírgula: '12, 23, 2x47'</span>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cotizar</button><br><br><br>
        </form>
```

At the Livewire class `Lead.php` the method:

```
public function cotizar(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->cotacao);
        $idades = explode(',', $request->cotacao);
        $precos = Preco::all();

        $resultado = [];

        foreach ($precos as $preco) {
            $plano = $preco->dados[0][1];
            foreach ($preco->dados as $dado) {
                if (in_array($dado[0], $idades)) {
                    $resultado[] = [
                        'idade' => $dado[0],
                        'preco' => $dado[1],
                        'plano' => $plano
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        dd($resultado);
    }
```

...and the dd result:

```
null // app/Http/Livewire/Lead.php:110
```

Anybody knows why I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't read [the docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation#introduction), since then you would know that Livewire doesn't work with such requests. You should be setting up `public` properties for your form fields that need to be submitted, which are then accessible simply using `$this->property`, which in your case would be: `$this->cotacao`

Answer (score 0):

Livewire don't use Request. Just need to change to:

```
 $idades = explode(',', $this->cotacao);
```